# running jquery.ajax causes to slow down in navigating to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have jquery.ajax that always requesting data to the server.My problem is that when I 
click  some navigation menu I can't navigate it is very too slow.I tried to comment the method inside the success,it works fine I can navigate very fast because there is no request running...Any Idea how to make this work to have request running at the same time and I can navigate to other page.?.

More input greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
  $(function(){
      getUpdates();

  });


   function getUpdates(){
           type: "GET",
           dataType:'json',
           url: "updates.php",
           error: function () {
               setTimeout(getUpdates, 5000);
           },
           success: function(data){
              //do something with the data
              ...
              ...
              ...
               getUpdates(); //call again the function

           }

       });

    }
```

Comment: try using `setTimeout(getUpdates, 5000);` inside `success:`, instead of `getUpdates();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to start a new request as soon as the previous request finishes. There is no (good) solution for your problem - the best idea is to restructure your code. Since you're constantly pooling the server for new information, you might want to look into [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) to implement some sort of push mechanism from the server.

That said, for a simple speedup, the best thing you can do is add a timeout in the success function, the same way you did with the error function.

Comment: How do I implement the socket I.O just like in my jquery.ajax ?

Comment: is 5 seconds is enough or it it just too fast?

Comment: That really depends on your server and the load it can take. As for the client, you can test it, but anything longer than 1 second should be OK.

In short, if you decide to keep it this way, you should make the wait **as long as possible** while still keeping the functionality you desire.